# Invalid View cannot be compiled

Tags: sql, view, oracle12c

I have an invaild view on my PROD system:

```
PROD.CLIENT
```

I found out that is invalid with following statement:

```
select
    owner c1,
    object_type c3,
    object_name c2
from
    dba_objects
where
    status != 'VALID'
order by
    owner,
    object_type;
```

I tried recompiling it but when I try the first statement it still shows up:

```
ALTER VIEW PROD.CLIENT COMPILE;
```

I also tried searching for user errors, but there are none:

```
SELECT * FROM user_errors;
```

How can I find the problem or error with my invalid view?

Comment: Just run the SELECT statement alone (without the CREATE VIEW) - Oracle will tell you what error you have.

Comment: When I select it I get the ORA-04063 error - it somehow says that a view column has a wrong reference that no longer exists or changed. Do you also know how I can find out what changed?

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I said. Don't SELECT FROM CLIENT, that's useless as the CLIENT view is invalid. Run `select owner, object type, ... from dba_objects where ...`. That *should* work in 12c because all columns you used exist in DBA_OBJECTS (as well is ALL_OBJECTS; they have the same description - see here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-AA6DEF8B-F04F-482A-8440-DBCB18F6C976.htm#REFRN20146). Did you try to **drop** the view and recreate it?

Comment: If you don't have the source query for the view you can get it from the `text` column in `dba_views`. You can run *that* query - as the view owner - to see what the problem is. Or query `dba_errors`.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM user_errors;
```

Will only find errors belonging to your current user.

You are re-compiling a view belonging to the `PROD` user and if that is not the user you are connected as then you will not see the errors.

Instead, you can use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM all_errors WHERE owner='PROD' and name = 'CLIENT';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should CREATE VIEW :

```
 CREATE VIEW example AS
 select
    owner c1,
    object_type c3,
    object_name c2
from
    dba_objects
where
    status != 'VALID'
order by
    owner,
    object_type;
--- and then 
SELECT * FROM example; -- call view
```

Comment: Leonardo already has the view, but it is **invalid**.

Comment: I want him to describe it more clearly

Comment: And the problematic view isn't of that query; that's the query they ran to identify the name of the invalid view.